# Problema com UPDATE de Tabela baseada em somatório de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Saudações a todos do fórum!

Como todos que começam a aprender MySQL, nos deparamos com problemas relativamente simples mas que não conseguimos resolver.

Criei a tabela INFO_PACOTES que armazena informações de pacotes que trafegam na minha rede. Os arquivos são processados via shell e armazenados somente o MAC de origem e o tamanho do pacote.

```
mysql> desc INFO_PACOTES;

| Field       | Type       |Null | Key |Default | Extra |

|mac_origem   |char(17)    |YES  |     | NULL   |       |

|tamanho_frame|decimal(5,0)|YES  |     | NULL   |       |
```

Como uma rede normal, diversos dispositivos são conectados e monitorados. Assim, haverão diversos dispositivos com diferentes MAC's.

Criei a tabela CONHECIDOS que está descrita abaixo. A única coisa que preciso é somar os valores da coluna tamanho_frame da tabela INFO_PACOTES agrupado por diferentes "mac_origem" e o resultado das somas atualizar o campo trafego_total da tabela CONHECIDOS.

```
|Field       |Type          |Null|Key|Default|Extra|


|mac         |char(17)      |NO  |PRI|NULL   |     |



|trafego_total|decimal(20,0)|YES |   |NULL   |     |
```

Criei a seguinte sentença abaixo:

```
UPDATE CONHECIDOS, INFO_PACOTES
    SET trafego_total =  (SELECT sum(tamanho_frame) FROM INFO_PACOTES 
    GROUP BY INFO_PACOTES.mac_origem) 
    WHERE CONHECIDOS.mac=INFO_PACOTES.mac_origem;
```

Ao final da sentença, o select resulta em mais de uma linha, gerando o erro:

> **ERROR 1242 (21000)**: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Alguém sabe me dizer o que estou errando?

Obrigado!

Comment: veja se minha resposta te ajuda

Comment: @CaioMoreti, mostrei uma maneira alternativa de se fazer essa consulta, incluindo a explicação do porquê ela não ter dado certo.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei porque você colocou

```
Update Conhecidos, InfoPacotes
```

já que apenas a tabela Conhecidos vai sofrer o update,

e o where, tem que ficar dentro do sub-select. Veja:

```
UPDATE CONHECIDOS SET trafego_total =  (SELECT sum(tamanho_frame) FROM INFO_PACOTES GROUP BY INFO_PACOTES.mac_origem where INFO_PACOTES.mac_origem =  CONHECIDOS.mac);
```

dessa forma todos os registros da tabela Conhecidos serão atualizados de uma vez só.

Comment: acho q nem precisa do group by nesse caso... só terá o mac correspondente do update mesmo

Comment: Eu havia pensado nisso também, porém, quando não informo  o nome da tabela INFO_PACOTES, é gerado o seguinte erro:

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where INFO_PACOTES.mac_origem =  CONHECIDOS.mac)' at line 1

Comment: @Robann, consegui o que eu queria. Era com o comando INNER JOIN.         

UPDATE CONHECIDOS
INNER JOIN 
    (
      select mac_origem, sum(tamanho_frame) total
      from INFO_PACOTES
      group by mac_origem
    ) INFO_PACOTES
ON CONHECIDOS.mac = INFO_PACOTES.mac_origem
SET CONHECIDOS.trafego_total = INFO_PACOTES.total

Answer (score 0):

Sua lógica estava quase certa. Faltaram dois detalhes.

Você não quer fazer um update baseado numa junção. Você quer fazer apenas baseado num agrupamento. Você quer que o tráfego total de determinado MAC address seja atualizado de acordo com a soma de todos os pacotes que passaram por aquele MAC.

Em MySQL 8.0, há o suporte a CTE, que ficaria mais ou menos assim o código:

```
WITH soma_trafego AS (
    SELECT
       mac_origem AS mac,
       SUM(tamanho_frame) AS total
    FROM
       info_pacotes
    GROUP BY
        mac_origem
 )
 UPDATE
     conhecidos
 SET
      trafego_total = (SELECT total FROM soma_trafego WHERE soma_trafego.mac = conhecidos.mac)
```

Outra forma com CTE que eu acho que é válida (não pude testar ainda):

```
WITH soma_trafego AS (
    SELECT
       mac_origem AS mac,
       SUM(tamanho_frame) AS total
    FROM
       info_pacotes
    GROUP BY
        mac_origem
 )
 UPDATE
     conhecidos, soma_total
 SET
      conhecidos.trafego_total = soma_total.total
WHERE
     soma_trafego.mac = conhecidos.mac
```

Se estiver usando uma versão do MySQL que ainda não suporta CTE, recomendo deixar apenas a subquey e remover a segunda tabela do `update`. Basicamente, fica a mesma coisa da primeira CTE, porém, digamos assim, a CTE é expandida na subquery:

```
UPDATE
     conhecidos
 SET
      trafego_total = (SELECT SUM(info_pacotes.tamanho_frame)  FROM  info_pacotes WHERE info_pacotes.mac_origem = conhecidos.mac GROUP BY info_pacotes.mac_origem)
```

### Sobre a sua query

Note que você referencia o uso da tabela de informação de pacotes duas vezes. A primeira vez, ela está no contexto da tabela `conhecidos`, e garante que só vai atualizar se tiver alguém cujo MAC combine com o MAC de algum pacote.

Na segunda vez que se usa a tabela, ela está no contexto de coluna de uma linha. Você agrupa por MAC de origem, mas em nenhum momento filtra esse MAC. Por não filtrar o MAC, você retorna múltiplas linhas para essa atualização. Se você fizer somente a subquery, verá isso acontecendo. Como são múltiplas linhas retornadas no contexto de uma colunas de uma linha, o SGBD se perde e lança esse aviso para você.